# manage.py migrate on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my django environment on aws linux 2023 and I have a file with command for migration:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

Then I get an error in cfn-init.log

```
2023-11-06 19:01:44,570 [ERROR] Command 01_migrate (source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate) failed
2023-11-06 19:01:44,570 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_hq_app: Command 01_migrate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
  CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 277, in build
  changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed
2023-11-06 19:01:44,571 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2023-11-06 19:01:44,571 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_migrate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 277, in build
changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed
```

Is command changed from linux2 to linux 2023?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the logs on the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment for more specific error messages that might help you diagnose the problem further. You can access the logs through the AWS Management Console or by using the EB CLI.

Comment: What log file are you referring to? I must have missed it because I looked through all of them

Comment: Actually you were right, I did find error after looking at thew logs more. Thank you for explaining that this error is the cause of some other error.